# Edit button toggles modal and load data from PHP using AJAX and JQUERY

Tags: beginner, jquery, html, ajax

I've been working on an edit/update button that will toggle a modal that looks like this:

[image: Update/Edit Employee Modal]

Is there a better code for this JavaScript code that I made?

```
<script>

$('body').on('click', '.editButton',function(){
    let edit = $(this).val()
    console.log("Edit this : " + edit);

    $('#updateEmpModal').modal('toggle');


    $.ajax({
        type    :   'POST',
        url     :   'get.php',
        data    :   {'edit' : edit},
        dataType:   'json',
        success: function(data){
            $("#updateEmpForm input[name='EMAIL']")         .val(data.EMAIL);
            $("#updateEmpForm input[name='PASSWORD']")      .val(data.PASSWORD);
            $("#updateEmpForm input[name='RIGHTS']")        .val(data.RIGHTS);
            $("#updateEmpForm input[name='LAST_NAME']")     .val(data.LAST_NAME);
            $("#updateEmpForm input[name='FIRST_NAME']")    .val(data.FIRST_NAME);
            $("#updateEmpForm input[name='MIDDLE_NAME']")   .val(data.MIDDLE_NAME);
            $("#updateEmpForm input[name='SUFFIX']")        .val(data.SUFFIX);
            $("#updateEmpForm input[name='GENDER']")        .val(data.GENDER);
            $("#updateEmpForm input[name='BIRTHDATE']")     .val(data.BIRTHDATE);
            $("#updateEmpForm input[name='BIRTHPLACE']")    .val(data.BIRTHPLACE);
            $("#updateEmpForm input[name='CITIZENSHIP']")   .val(data.CITIZENSHIP);
            $("#updateEmpForm input[name='RELIGION']")      .val(data.RELIGION);
            $("#updateEmpForm input[name='ADDRESS']")       .val(data.ADDRESS);
            $("#updateEmpForm input[name='CONTACT']")       .val(data.CONTACT);
            $("#updateEmpForm input[name='ICE_NAME']")      .val(data.ICE_NAME);
            $("#updateEmpForm input[name='ICE_CONTACT']")   .val(data.ICE_CONTACT);
            $("#updateEmpForm input[name='DEPARTMENT']")    .val(data.DEPARTMENT);
            $("#updateEmpForm input[name='POSITION']")      .val(data.POSITION);
            $("#updateEmpForm input[name='EMP_TYPE']")      .val(data.EMP_TYPE);
            $("#updateEmpForm input[name='edit']")          .val(data.ID);
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

It is working, but I want to know if this is a bad practice and if there are better solutions.

Comment: Safe to remove the php tag here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Code Review! Hopefully you enjoy using this site and receive valuable feedback.

---

Wow, what patience you have to type out/copy all of those lines to update the form inputs. Instead of doing that, you could loop through the input fields and check if the name matches a key in the returned data. One can use [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each) to iterate over the input fields, then check the name using [`.attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr) and the [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator.

```
$('#updateEmpForm input').each(function() {
    const inputName = $(this).attr('name');
    if (inputName in data) {
        $(this).val(data[key]);
    }
});
```

To exclude certain fields, like any password inputs, the selector could be updated to include pseudo-class selectors like [`:not()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) - for example:

```
$('#updateEmpForm input:not([type="password"])').each(function() {
```

That should handle all but the last repeated line - which can be included before or after the call to `.each()`:

```
$("#updateEmpForm input[name='edit']").val(data.ID);
```

You could also define a mapping of input names to keys and look in the mapping for values. For example:

```
const inputNameKeyMapping = {
    edit: 'ID',
    //any other names that don't match keys directly
}
```

And use that mapping when assigning the value - something like:

```
$('#updateEmpForm input').each(function() {
    const inputName = $(this).attr('name');
    const key = inputNameKeyMapping[inputName] || inputName;
    if (key in data) {
```

That way you wouldn't need to include manual value settings lines.

---

Also, instead the click handler can be simplified from:

> ```
> $('body').on('click', '.editButton',function(){
> ```

To using the [`.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click)  (short-cut) method on only elements with that class name `editButton`:

```
$('.editButton').click(function(){
```

---

I see `let` is used to declare the variable `edit`:

> ```
> let edit = $(this).val()
> ```

However, that value is never re-assigned. To avoid unintentional re-assignment, you could use [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) instead.

```
const edit = $(this).val()
```

And it is best to be consistent with line terminators - if most lines have them then make sure all do.